# Como combinar patrones de diseño POO

Tags: java, poo, patrones-de-diseño

Necesito una guía o consejos.

¿Como le hago para saber como combinar y cuando aplicar los patrones de diseño?

Tengo una tarea, la cual consiste en combinar almenos 2 patrones de diseño, pero no encuentro la manera en idear algun ejemplo.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Como combino patrones? Ya me lei cada uno, e incluso eh visto ejemplo en singular, pero enserio me bloqueo a la hora de combinarlos. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola José, esta pregunta es muy amplia... Hay muchísimos patrones de diferentes tipos. Además, no hay una forma *estándar* de combinarlos. Eso se hace según la necesidad del proyecto. Vas a tener que afinar un poco más para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Como dice @DavidDPG, es todo en base la necesidad del proyecto. No siempre necesitaras el patron Observer o Command en todos los proyectos. Como ya sabes la teoria y quizas la practica. Ahora te toca encontrar el caso adecuado para un patron o el otro.

Comment: La persona que lo preguntó puro satisfacer su inquietud. Si es una pregunta conceptual también sería valida, o no es posible satisfacer inquietudes conceptuales por este medio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más importante acerca de la aplicación de patrones es que cada uno tiene un contexto y una fórmula para aplicarlos. Los patrones puedes ser creacionales, estructurales o de comportamiento.

La combinación de ellos tiene que ver netamente con el análisis del contexto, por ejemplo, puedes combinar el strategy para liberar de dependencias y dejar extensibles métodos de una clase (Patrón de comportamiento), y también puedes aplicar un Singletton o Factory method (Patrón creacional).

Te sugiero seguir leyendo ejemplos y teoría. Luego toma cualquier cosa (por ejemplo cómo funciona un cajero automático) e ir definiendo los comportamientos que existen, y encontrar la aplicabilidad de los patrones.

Te dejo un [link](https://sourcemaking.com) muy explicativo para tener de guía (En Inglés).

Saludos y suerte

Comment: Que suave página. Muy concreta y especifica. Gracias.

Comment: No hay problema. si te sirvió califica la respuesta. Saludos